# Ubuntu login freezing

Tags: login

When I boot up my computer I come to the welcome screen, when I type in my password and hit enter the text box go's away and just stays there I'm using 13.10 if you have any idea please help.

Answer (score 0):

Use text mode - Clt+Alt+F1 to login with text mode for further investigation. If yo can go to text mode, there is some problem with graphics.
Have you been using the 13.10 for sometime and then this happened or right after installation ?